# Strange Behaviour by adding a buuton event via DOM JavaScript

Tags: javascript, dom

I want to add a JavaScript function via DOM to my Homepage. I am using a Json String to get the elements. Everything is running fine but I have an issue the Javascript function has always the same parameter and the parameter is not changing no matter which button i click. The paramater is alwys the last value "name" of the jso string. How to iterate the correct way through the json and build up the DOM document? here is my code

```
var jsonData = JSON.parse(jsonstring);
let element = document.getElementById("fi");
while (element.firstChild) {
  element.removeChild(element.firstChild);
}

for (var i = 0; i < jsonData.files.length; i++) {
  // Now create and append to iDiv
  var innerNameDiv = document.createElement('div');
  innerNameDiv.className = 'ccl ccu';
  innerNameDiv.style.float = "left";
  innerNameDiv.style.width = "45%";
  innerNameDiv.innerHTML = "&nbsp;&nbsp;" + jsonData.files[i].name;
  var innerFileSizeDiv = document.createElement('div');
  innerFileSizeDiv.className = 'cct ccu';
  innerFileSizeDiv.style.float = "left";
  innerFileSizeDiv.style.width = "30%";
  innerFileSizeDiv.textContent = jsonData.files[i].filesize;
  var innerButtonDiv = document.createElement('div');
  innerButtonDiv.className = 'ccr ccu';
  innerButtonDiv.style.float = "left";
  innerButtonDiv.style.width = "20%";
  var innerButtonDelete = document.createElement("button");
  innerButtonDelete.class = "b";
  innerButtonDelete.innerText = "Del";
  var filename = jsonData.files[i].name;
  innerButtonDelete.addEventListener('click', () => {
    deleteFile(filename)
  });
  innerButtonDiv.appendChild(innerButtonDelete);


  element.appendChild(innerNameDiv);
  element.appendChild(innerFileSizeDiv);
  element.appendChild(innerButtonDiv);

  console.log(jsonData.files[i].name + ":" + jsonData.files[i].filesize);
}
```

Json string is for example :

```
{"files":[{"name":"1","filesize":32},{"name":"2","filesize":32},{"name":"3","filesize":32},{"name":"4","filesize":32}]}
```

No matter which button I click it will be always with parameter 4 and not any different.

Answer (score 0):

Use the event to see what the source button is, the `.target`.

```
for (let i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++) {
  buttons[i].addEventListener("click", function (evt) {
    console.log(evt.target.className)
  });
}
```

Comment: Should i use this code in the delteFile function?

Comment: you run this iteration after your document has the buttons rendered.